# Есть ли ошибка в предложении?

Tags: грамматика

Мы придумываем стишок в школьную газету о здоровом образе жизни. Там есть предложение: "Хорошо, когда здоровым ты листаешь календарь". Редактор Word указал на ошибку: "здоровым". Если изменить на "здоровый", то Word пропускает, но, по-моему, становится как-то непонятно: "здоровый ребенок листает календарь" или "ребенок листает здоровый календарь".

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, вполне приемлемым Ваш вариант стихотворения. Ничего исправлять не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за поддержку!

Answer (score 0):

Несколько коряво. Уж лучше так: "Плохо, если ты болеешь и листаешь календарь."

Comment: Дело в том, что весь стишок - в положительном ключе, не хотелось бы в последнем предложении такую грустную развязку.

Answer (score 0):

Нормальное стихотворение. А Ворд и слово "голубой" подчеркивает как ошибку, что с него взять)))

Answer (score 0):

Отличный стишок, а компьютеру полёта творчества не понять!